# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when calling a task function to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, async-await

I have the following code in a controller.

```
private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
        private ApplicationDbContext userDB;
        public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
        {
            get
            {
                return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            private set
            {
                _userManager = value;
            }
        }

        public async Task SendEmail(string user_id, string subject, string user_email )
        {
            await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user_id, subject, user_email);
        }

public ActionResult Transfer(int id, int nurse_id, int ambulance_id, int driver_id, int nurse_account_id)
        {
            ...
            /////////////////////////////////
            //Send email
            string nurse_user_id = db.Nurse_Account.Where(m => m.nurse_account_id == call.nurse_account_id).Select(m => m.nurse_account_user_id).First();
            string usr = db.AspNetUsers.Where(m => m.Id == nurse_user_id).Select(m => m.Id).First();
            string usr_mail = db.AspNetUsers.Where(m => m.Id == nurse_user_id).Select(m => m.Email).First();

            SendEmail(usr, "New call", usr_mail);

            ////////////////////////////////
            ...
            return Json(new { result = "OK" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

When I'm calling `SendEmail` function I get the following break error:

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.<>c.<ThrowAsyncIfNecessary>b__18_0(Object s)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
```

Comment: You need to await the SendEmail task

Comment: You don't show us where the error is. What is `UserManager`, is it supposed to be `_userManager`? You also need to await the `SendMail` method, otherwise the object might get disposed before the mail is sent.

Comment: Also, please 1. format your code properly and 2. only give us code that is relevant to the question. With 3k+ rep you should know this by now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you're seeing is due to request-extrinsic code. All request-extrinsic code is dangerous.

Specifically, the code is calling `SendEmail` but not `await`ing the result. So it's trying to do a kind of "fire-and-forget". After it calls `SendEmail` then it sends the response back to the client, leaving `SendEmail` running as request-extrinsic code.

However, `SendEmail` is called within the ASP.NET request context, and so when it tries to resume executing after its `await`, it runs into the error because that ASP.NET request context is gone. The response has already been sent, so there's no more ASP.NET request context.

The best solution is to remove the request-extrinsic code. Either `await` the call to `SendEmail` or [build a basic distributed architecture for asynchronous messaging](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html). I would say just to use the `await` unless you *must* return early, in which case you need a durable queue and a worker process. The MVC action would write a message into the queue including all the email details, and then it would return the HTTP result. The worker process would read that queue and send the actual email.

Any other solution would use [request-extrinsic code, which is inherently dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html). Specifically, any request-extrinsic code may stop working without warning and without logs. "Fire and forget" **literally** means "forget". It's possible that work (emails in this case) may be lost. But if you're OK with that, then you can call the request-extrinsic code in a way that it does not reference the ASP.NET request context by using something like [`NoContext` from my AsyncEx library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/8a73d0467d40ca41f9f9cf827c7a35702243abb8/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronizationContextSwitcher.cs#L36-L56).

Comment: Thank you Stephen! My new code now is:
`public async Task<ActionResult> Transfer(int id, int nurse_id, int ambulance_id, int driver_id, int nurse_account_id)
        {
         ...
          await SendEmail(usr, "New call", usr_mail);
         }`